# Java: Can't check the boolean for null

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

if a HashMap is empty and I check for `.containsKey()`
I get a null answer.

My Problem is that If I want to check for null I get an error message

```
if(containsKey == null || !containsKey){
```

I receive the error message

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'boolean', 'null'
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening. I thought that this should work

Comment: `containsKey` seems to be of type `boolean`, so how can that ever be `null`? Why do you think it can be?

Answer (score 6):

Check that the map isn't `null` (not that [`HashMap.containsKey(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) returned `null`, because it didn't - it can't. It returns a `boolean` primitive, which can only be `true` or `false`).

```
if (map != null && map.containsKey(someKey)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HashMap .isEmpty() method to check if your hashmap is empty or not.

Comment: Yeah but I cant check if it is empty if it doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

containsKey can't be null as it is the method being called. Try checking if the map itself is null.

Comment: No worries. I was hoping to lead you to the answer as I find that helps people learn but guy above gave you the answer so that's good I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Booleans are primitives, and **primitives will never be null.**
Only Object classes can be null.

Following this argument, you **can** do this for object class *Integer*:

```
Integer myObject = 1;

if (myObject != null){
    ...
}
```

But you **cannot** do this for *int*, which is a primitive like booleans:

```
int myPrimitve = 1;

if (myPrimitve == null){
    ...
}
```

Your IDE will show the error *Operator == cannot be applied to int, null*